# How to trim a svg image in markdown file

Tags: svg, trim, image-clipping

I have a svg file, made by Google Drawings. (The `png` version is shown below

[image]

and the `svg` code is below

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0.0 0.0 960.0 720.0" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><clipPath id="p.0"><path d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0l0 -720.0z" clip-rule="nonzero"/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#p.0)"><path fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.0" d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0z" fill-rule="evenodd"/><path fill="#999999" d="m393.1811 309.8189l0 0c0 -37.33795 30.268372 -67.60631 67.60632 -67.60631l0 0c17.930298 0 35.12622 7.1227875 47.80487 19.801437c12.67865 12.678619 19.801392 29.874542 19.801392 47.80487l0 0c0 37.33792 -30.268341 67.60629 -67.60626 67.60629l0 0c-37.33795 0 -67.60632 -30.268372 -67.60632 -67.60629z" fill-rule="evenodd"/><path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" d="m393.1811 309.8189l0 0c0 -37.33795 30.268372 -67.60631 67.60632 -67.60631l0 0c17.930298 0 35.12622 7.1227875 47.80487 19.801437c12.67865 12.678619 19.801392 29.874542 19.801392 47.80487l0 0c0 37.33792 -30.268341 67.60629 -67.60626 67.60629l0 0c-37.33795 0 -67.60632 -30.268372 -67.60632 -67.60629z" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g></svg>
```

My purpose is to insert this `svg` image into a markdown file `my_work.md`. As you can see, there are lots of white space in the image, I want to trim them off and only show the useful part. In this example, the useful part is just the grey circle.

I have some general ideas, but don't know to to realise them.

- Direct method: use some markdown tricks to trim it.
- Indirect method: load this image in Python and trim it using some Python library, export the trimmed svg-image and use it in md-file.
- Indirect method: trim it in Google Drawings.

Could you please tell me how to do it? Any method is welcomed. I just need to only show the useful part of the image. Please note that I have many svg-files, and the useful part may not be in the center of the image.

Comment: Can you remove this path: `<path fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.0" d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>` This is a transparent path but you may need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your example I've added `id`s in order to be able to talk about your paths.

Path `a` and `b` are identical and they arte large rectangles that cover the whole svg canvas. Path `a` is not visible since is inside a `clipPath` and path `b` is transparent: `fill-opacity="0.0"`

Also path `c` and path `d` are identical. You may remove one of then and add both the stroke and the fill to the same path. Alternatively you put the path `c` inside a `<defs>` and use it twice: once for the fill and once for the stroke if this is what you need.

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0.0 0.0 960.0 720.0" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<clipPath id="p.0">
<path id="a" d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0l0 -720.0z" clip-rule="nonzero"/></clipPath>

<g clip-path="url(#p.0)">

<path id="b" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.0" d="m0 0l960.0 0l0 720.0l-960.0 0z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>

<path  id="c" fill="#999999" d="m393.1811 309.8189l0 0c0 -37.33795 30.268372 -67.60631 67.60632 -67.60631l0 0c17.930298 0 35.12622 7.1227875 47.80487 19.801437c12.67865 12.678619 19.801392 29.874542 19.801392 47.80487l0 0c0 37.33792 -30.268341 67.60629 -67.60626 67.60629l0 0c-37.33795 0 -67.60632 -30.268372 -67.60632 -67.60629z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>

<path  id="d" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" d="m393.1811 309.8189l0 0c0 -37.33795 30.268372 -67.60631 67.60632 -67.60631l0 0c17.930298 0 35.12622 7.1227875 47.80487 19.801437c12.67865 12.678619 19.801392 29.874542 19.801392 47.80487l0 0c0 37.33792 -30.268341 67.60629 -67.60626 67.60629l0 0c-37.33795 0 -67.60632 -30.268372 -67.60632 -67.60629z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>

</g>

</svg>
```

*In order to remove the white space* you may delete path `b`,get the size of path `c` and use it for the viewBox attribute: in this case `viewBox="391 240 139 139"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="391 240 139 139" stroke-miterlimit="10" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <path fill="#999999" stroke="black" d="m393.1811 309.8189l0 0c0 -37.33795 30.268372 -67.60631 67.60632 -67.60631l0 0c17.930298 0 35.12622 7.1227875 47.80487 19.801437c12.67865 12.678619 19.801392 29.874542 19.801392 47.80487l0 0c0 37.33792 -30.268341 67.60629 -67.60626 67.60629l0 0c-37.33795 0 -67.60632 -30.268372 -67.60632 -67.60629z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  
  
</svg>
```